# TMediaplayer gets Freed because of ARC before file plays

Tags: ios, delphi, automatic-ref-counting, firemonkey

Here is a example of a TMediaplayer playing a file

```
var
    Med : TMediaplayer;
begin
  Med := TMediaPlayer.Create(self);
  Med.FileName := TPath.Combine(TPath.GetDocumentsPath, 'sound.caf');
  Med.Play;
end;
```

The File plays, but because I give it a owner I create a reference  and the refcount increases and the destructor is never called and thus it is never freed, and memory is leaked.

And if I create it with no owner

```
Med := TMediaPlayer.Create(nil);
```

The moment I reach the `end;` the refcount drops to 0 and the TMediaPlayer destructor is called.

Comment: Rule on SO: One **Question** -> **One** Question - For each question, post an individual question

Comment: I simply showed my research effort as recommended by SO, but yes I see I was asking more than 1 question

Comment: Your question contained **two** questions: 1. Reference count/Freeing instance 2. Notification on `TMediaPlayer` state. I just removed the second part. Feel free to ask the second part in a new question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `TMediaPlayer` instance will be freed, when the owner is freed. If you want to free the `TMediaPlayer` instance by hand then you have to `DisposeOf` the instance.

To know the reference of that instance, you have to store the reference into a local field.

```
type
  TSomeForm = class( TForm )
  private
    FMediaPlayer: TMediaPlayer;
    procedure PlaySomeSound();
  end;

procedure TSomeForm.PlaySomeSound();
begin
  // force destruction for ARC/NONARC platforms
  FMediaPlayer.DisposeOf(); // this is also safe, if FMediaPlayer is nil
  FMediaPlayer := TMediaPlayer.Create( Self );
  FMediaPlayer.FileName := TPath.Combine(TPath.GetDocumentsPath, 'sound.caf');
  FMediaPlayer.Play;
end;
```

This code works on ARC and NONARC platforms.

Answer (score 4):

Your `Med` variable goes out of scope when the procedure quits, so it makes sense that ARC cleans it up at that point.

You should define your variable somewhere else, perhaps in your form.